# mysql filter column results

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following data.

| ID | heade |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | blue |
| 100 | black |
| 100 | orange |
| 101 | brown |
| 101 | green |
| 102 | green |
| 102 | white |
| 102 | yellow |
| 103 | yellow |
| 103 | blue |
|  |  |

Intended results: If I select blue, I want to get  100 and 103. If Select blue and yellow return only 103. if I select blue yellow and white, no results should be returned. Basically I want to get only the PID columns that match all the selected colors.
NB: the IN SQL statement will only give me PID that contains any colors mentioned in the statement. I need my criteria to be met as explained above. Let me have have your thought. I'm open to all suggestions even if the solution will involve a combination of sql query for the initial results, and then a json object to filter as required

I have tried the IN in the WHERE predicate clause but this only gives me PID that match any colors in the statement

Comment: Did you try anything : Like using `GROUP BY` and `HAVING`

Comment: How many elements in your query?  Always two (example: 'blue' and 'yellow'), or a variable number?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT ID, COUNT(DISTINCT heade) AS num_colours
FROM mytable
WHERE heade IN ('blue', 'white')
GROUP BY ID
HAVING num_colours = 2
```

Comment: NB If you know that there are always going to be 2 elements in the query, then you could also use a subselect, which might be more performant

Answer (score 1):

This can be generalised as :

```
SELECT ID
FROM your_table
WHERE heade IN ('Color1', 'Colo2', 'Color3'......'Colorn')
GROUP BY ID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT heade) = n;
```

You can pass the exact colors and their count as 'n'. Here is a [DBFILLDLE demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/0WaLi3C1).

When you pass three colors :

```
SELECT ID
FROM your_table
WHERE heade IN ('blue', 'yellow', 'white')
GROUP BY ID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT heade) = 3;
```

Outout : Empty.

When you pass two colors :

```
SELECT ID
FROM your_table
WHERE heade IN ('blue', 'yellow')
GROUP BY ID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT heade) = 2;
```

Output :

```
ID
103
```

When you pass single color :

```
SELECT ID
FROM your_table
WHERE heade IN ('blue')
GROUP BY ID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT heade) = 1;
```

Output :

```
ID
100
103
```

Comment: Great answers Tushar and Rob, having count was the missing link. Many thanks to everyone for their invaluable input